# MySQL-выбрать строки из двух таблиц с разными условиями выборки

Tags: mysql

День добрый. Прошу помощи. Ни как не могу одолеть выборку из 3 таблиц

Таблица 1 orders (хранит информацию о заказах)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица 2 orders_info (хранит дополнительную информацию о заказах)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица 3 orders_movement (хранит действия с заказами (оплаты, смена статуса заказа, доставка,...))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно найти в таблице 2 (orders_info) строки где

```
name = 'Status'
```

а так же

```
value <> '6' AND value <> '8' AND value <> '11' AND value <> '14'
```

Помимо этого нужно еще из таблицы 3 orders_movement выбирать только те строки в которых

```
type = 'status'
```

а так же

```
value <> '5'
```

(означает что заказ оплачен) При этом в этой таблице может быть несколько записей для одного заказа, имеющие

> type = 'status'

но с разными значениями

> value

По отдельности я могу вывести или первое или второе условия, но вот вместе не получается

Так

```
WHERE value <> '6' AND value <> '8' AND value <> '11' AND value <> '14'
```

Выводятся все заказы за исключением тех, у которых value будет 6, 8, 11, 14

Так

```
WHERE o.id NOT IN(select order_id from order_movement om WHERE om.type = 'status' AND om.value =5)
```

я могу вывести все заказы, которые не были оплачены (не было смены status на 5).

запрос сам вызлядит так

```
SELECT o.id FROM orders AS o
                LEFT JOIN orders_info AS sr ON sr.record = o.id AND sr.name = 'Status'
                WHERE sr.value <> '6' AND sr.value <> '8' AND sr.value <> '11' AND o.id NOT IN(select order_id from #__can_order_movement om WHERE om.type = 'status' AND om.value =5);
```

Но он возвращает только неоплаченные заказы

Что нужно мне.

Таблица 1 orders

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name 1 |
| 2 | name 2 |
| 3 | name 3 |
| 4 | name 4 |

Таблица 2 orders_info

| record | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Discont | 0 |
| 1 | Quantity | 10 |
| **1** | **Status** | **8** |
| 2 | Discont | 1 |
| 2 | Quantity | 5 |
| **2** | **Status** | **14** |
| 3 | Discont | 1 |
| 3 | Quantity | 25 |
| **3** | **Status** | **14** |
| 4 | Discont | 5 |
| 4 | Quantity | 7 |
| **4** | **Status** | **10** |

Таблица 3 orders_movement

| order_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | payment | 200 |
| **1** | **status** | **5** |
| **2** | **status** | **5** |
| **2** | **status** | **14** |
| **3** | **status** | **14** |
| **2** | **status** | **7** |
| 4 | payment | 300 |
| **4** | **status** | **5** |

Итоговая таблица (что должно быть выведено)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | name 3 |
| 4 | name 4 |

Первую запись не выводим, так как в таблице 2 orders_info она имеет value 8. В данном случае все равно имеется в таблице 3 orders_movement запись value 5 или нет. Это касается и value 6, 8, 11. Только для value 14 должно быть еще одно условия в виде записи value 5 в таблице 3 orders_movement.

Вторую запись не выводим, так как в таблице 2 orders_info она имеет value 14, а так же в таблице 3 orders_movement она имеет value 5.

Третью запись выводим, так как в таблице orders_movement она не имеет value 5, хоть в таблице 2 orders_info она имеет value 14.

Четвертую запись выводим, так как в таблице 2 orders_info она имеет value 10, хоть в таблице 3 orders_movement она имеет value 5.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: видимо вам там условия надо просто через OR объединить и все на этом

Comment: замените подзапрос на левый джойн с теми же условиями, а where станет а-ля `sr.value NOT IN (5,8,11,14) OR om.order_id IS NULL` , или нет?

Comment: Если объединить через  OR таким образом  `WHERE sr.value <> '6' AND sr.value <> '8' AND sr.value <> '11' OR o.id NOT IN(select order_id from #__can_order_movement om WHERE om.type = 'status' AND om.value =5)` то первая час игнорируется. т.е выводятся записи даже если во второй таблице они имеют value 6, 8, 11

Comment: _sr.value NOT IN (5,8,11,14) OR om.order_id IS NULL_ - нет, не работает как нужно. Еще раз напишу что нужно - вывести все все записи из таблицы 1 orders если в таблице 2 orders_info **value** не равно **6**, **8**, **11**, а также **14**, но при условии, что у этого заказа в таблице 3 orders_movement хоть в одной строке **value** равен  **5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода только нужных строк, подцепляем из таблиц 2 и 3 строки, содержащие условия, которые нам нам не нужны, и проверяем, что такие не подцепились.

```
select o.id, o.name
from orders o
left join orders_info oi on (oi.record = o.id and oi.Discont='Status' and oi.value in (6,8,11,14))
left join orders_movement om on (om.order_id = o.id and om.type = 'status' and om.value = 5)
where oi.record is null or oi.value = 14 and om.order_id is null
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не выполняется здесь условие _а также 14, но при условии, что у этого заказа в таблице 3 orders_movement хоть в одной строке value равен 5_

Comment: Да, немного ошибся во втором условии. Должно быть ```or oi.value = 14 and om.order_id is null```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!! Все работает!!!